# Does Backswing work with double weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, fighter, double-weapons

> Backswing (Ex): At 7th level, when a two-handed fighter makes a full attack with a two-handed weapon, he adds double his Strength bonus on damage rolls for all attacks after the first.

All double weapons qualify as Two-handed weapons. So the question is while using both sides of a double weapon would the two-handed fighter ability Backswing apply?

Answer (score 4):

## Technically yes, but when using both ends to TWF, most tables say no

A double weapon is a type of two-handed weapon; every double weapon in the game is listed in the appropriate Two-Handed Weapon table. The rules for double weapons state that, when you use both ends of one in conjunction with the Two-Weapon Fighting option, the double weapon is treated as if the two ends of the weapon were a one-handed and light weapon, respectively, *for the purpose of TWF attack penalties.* Nothing defines them as such for any other purpose, so aside from deciding your attack penalties from Two-Weapon Fighting, double weapons are two-handed weapons.

Therefore, double weapons are two-handed weapons, and therefore benefit from Backswing, no matter how they are used.

However, please note that though this is technically true *even when you use Two-Weapon Fighting*, this is widely, if not universally, regarded as a rules oversight. The rules also specifically mention using only one end as a two-handed weapon, which would be a meaningless option if you could use both ends as two-handed weapons. Thus, most tables treat double weapons as if the ends were separate weapons *for all purposes*, rather than just for TWF attack penalties, while you use Two-Weapon Fighting.

Aside from my own games, I have only played under exactly one DM who allowed double weapons to function as two-handed weapons for all purposes (other than TWF attack penalties) even when used for TWF. In addition to Backswing, this implies that you get 1½×Str to damage with both ends, and you get the improved Power Attack damage bonus that two-handers get with both ends. Since every double weapon in the game is *quite* weak, I think this is appropriate benefit for them.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes and no.

A [double weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#wpn-quality-double) takes two hands to use, but only counts as a one-handed and light weapon when you are attacking with both ends.  In order to use a double weapon to make a two-handed attack, you have to only use one end at a time:

> The character can also choose to use a double weapon two-handed, attacking with only one end of it.

If you're using both ends, you can't make a two-handed attack.

Comment: Technically inaccurate, though almost-universally how things ruled.